# Can I prevent having to build docker whenever I add a new npm module?

Tags: docker

With this configuration I need to run `docker run build` whenever I add a new module in package.json. I wonder if there was a way to avoid that?

```
FROM node:lts as dependencies

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ui/package.json /app
COPY ./ui/yarn.lock /app

RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:lts as runner

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY ./ui /app

ARG GIT_COMMIT_HASH ""
ENV GIT_COMMIT_HASH "${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}"

ARG GIT_COMMIT_TAG ""
ENV GIT_COMMIT_TAG "${GIT_COMMIT_TAG}"

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/app/scripts/start-server.sh"]
CMD ["production"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker's standard model is that images are immutable.  Whenever you make any change to an application's code, libraries, or other assets, you need to rebuild the image and recreate any container that's running from it.  This applies not just to the `package.json` but also to your Javascript code, library dependencies and code in other languages, and normal compiled languages as well.

The flip side of this is that there's no requirement to use Docker all the time for everything.  You should be able to use an ordinary non-Docker Node setup for day-to-day development, and rebuild this image only when you need to do integration testing or push up to production.

For Node applications in particular, I've seen setups that replace absolutely everything in the image with volume mounts.  A typical Compose setup would look like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      # Replace all of the code in the image with host content
      - .:/app
      # Then replace the host's node_modules tree with an anonymous volume
      - /app/node_modules
```

With this setup, it's theoretically possible to run

```bash
docker-compose run app npm add foo
docker-compose restart app
```

to avoid rebuilding the image.

But: with this setup you're not actually using anything in the image besides Node, so you may as well specify `image: node` rather than using a custom Dockerfile; and if you're at this point, your workflow is identical to a non-Docker setup except that you're prefixing every `npm` command with `docker-compose run app`.